# Selecting Objects with a Variable/Property

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is the Code.

```
        private PingReply PingIt(object sender, string ip)
        {
            Ping p = new Ping();
            return p.Send(ip);
        }
        private void UpdateIcons(Icon e_Icon)
        {
            this.Icon = e_Icon;
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = this.Icon.ToBitmap();
            MyIcon.Icon = this.Icon;
        }
```

In my resource file i have two icons "Success" and "Bad", how would i select the right icon just by basically using Properties.Resources.p.Status.ToString() instead of having to use a switch or if/else?

Comment: Well, in `PingReply`, all `Status` values except, IIRC, `0` mean a failure. So, something like `Image image = PingReply.Status == 0 ? GoodBitmap : BadBitmap;`. Btw, don't get the Images directly from the Resources. Assign a Resource-generated Image to Bitmap objects and use those. Or use a custom class object to store the Bitmaps and have a public method/property that accept a `PingReply.Status` value and returns a Bitmap, so you have all the Logic in one place.

Answer (score 1):

There must be at least one decision (if/else) to determine which icon to use.

Here is my suggestion using properties (`Success` and `Failure`) but it can be done in various ways. 
`MYAPP`=the namespace of your application:

```
private Bitmap _Success;
private Bitmap Success
{
    get
    {
        if (_Success == null)
        {
            _Success = new Bitmap(MYAPP.Properties.Resources.success);
        }

        return _Success; ;
    }
}

private Bitmap _Failure;
private Bitmap Failure
{
    get
    {
        if (_Failure == null)
        {
            _Failure = new Bitmap(MYAPP.Properties.Resources.failure);
        }

        return _Failure;
    }
}

// use when there is no need for the bitmaps/form is closed
private void DisposeBitmaps()
{
    if (_Success != null)
    {
        _Success.Dispose();
    }
    if (_Failure != null)
    {
        _Failure.Dispose();
    }
}


    private void UpdateIcons(IPStatus status)
    {
        if (status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Success;
        }
        else
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Failure;
        }
    }

    private void TryPing()
    {
        var p = PingIt(new object(), "8.8.8.8");
        UpdateIcons(p.Status);
    }

    private static PingReply PingIt(object sender, string ip)
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
        return p.Send(ip);
    }
```